# wp_nav_menu doesn't work in a duplicate server

Tags: php, menus

I duplicated my Wordpress installation to move to another server. Everything works find except one single file. I created a header-shop.php file to call a certain menu on my shop page. In the first server it was working. In the new one, it doesn't. It seems to me really crazy.

Here is the file:

```
<!doctype html>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<section class="grid wrapper shoptopmenu" id="content">
<div class="shop-menu">
<?php

$defaults = array(
    'menu'            => 'shop-top-menu',
    'container'       => 'nav',
    'container_class' => 'grid wrapper',
    'container_id'    => 'shopmenue',
    'menu_class'      => 'unit full grid',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>
</div>
```

In the first server, the HTML code is:

```
<section class="grid wrapper shoptopmenu" id="content">
    <div class="shop-menu">
        <nav id="shopmenue" class="grid wrapper">
            <ul id="menu-shop-top-menu" class="unit full grid">
            .....
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

In the new server, the HTML code is:

```
<section class="grid wrapper shoptopmenu" id="content">
    <div class="shop-menu">
        <div class="unit full grid">
            <ul>
            ....
            </ul>
        </div>
```

You can see that the `nav` element and the id and class on the `ul` element are missing. Everything else is the same. Any idea before get crazy? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu data is in the database. In order to have an exact copy, you need to copy the files and all the items in the database as well.

Verify if all the needed elements from the database are present in the wordpress admin and or with phpmyadmin.

Alternatively, after these lines in your PHP file :
`<div class="shop-menu">
<?php`

you can put the following piece of code:

`$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object('shop-top-menu');
$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
    print '<pre>';
    var_dump($menu_items );

    print '</pre>';`

to check if wordpress can find the menu data at all:

If the output is:

`array(0) { }`

Wordpress cannot find the menu and something went wrong during the copying process.

Comment: Of course. I used the duplicator plugin which does both of them. I have used it numerous times before without a problem. As I mention, everything else works as it should in the website.

Comment: ok good, is the menu present in the wp-backend?

Comment: Yes. And also tried to save it again, in case something had broken on the DB.

Comment: When you put this code after: `<div class="shop-menu">
<?php` - is the output exactly the same?   `$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object('shop-top-menu');
  
  $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
  

  print '<pre>';
  var_dump($menu_items );
  print '</pre>';
  die();
`

Comment: It might be a caching issue as well, have you tried disabling caching plugin (if you use one) and/or viewing the site in incognito mode?

Comment: This is the result if I add the code you suggest `array(0) {
}`

Comment: Then it cannot find the menu, try adding another menu, and see if that one works. Also - the menu 'shop-top-menu' might not be loaded yet, but that would be weird if it works on the other server.

Comment: I dug a little more. If I create a menu from the `Appearance->Menu` it works. However, the menu from the original server was created from customizer because the Product Categories weren't available on the Admin. Every menu created from there, doesn't work.

Comment: That is good news! Now you have a starting point. I cannot tell what causes this, perhaps duplicator did not copy everything. Maybe this will provide you with some info. Good luck! https://wordpress.org/support/topic/duplicator-does-not-copy-all-files

Comment: I chose your answer as the best since you helped through the comments. Please update your answer with the summary of those so it would be easier for the next readers.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely (close to 100%) the database didn't import fully. Set `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` to check then repair the database somehow. For me, converting from My